# setting the output for l200c - am I correct in how it works

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm trying to use a [L200C](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00000053.pdf) voltage regulator as a pre-regulator for my PSU since that all I have. I noticed it has a voltage divider between the pin 2 and 4. Am I correct in saying the limiting pin output a 2.77 V into the voltage divider to set the output voltage. So the 2.77 V will a internal reference voltage. The R2 and R1 resistor network is feedback part of a internal non inverting amplifier. Yes?

[image]

So if I want something that's Arduino programmable, all I need is a circuit to feed the appropriate voltage yes? If so I would greatly appreciate it if I can be directed to some more information.

[image: L200c]

Comment: We're supposed to inherently know what a L200C is!?  You mention pin 4, but you schematic shows no pin numbers. -1 for poorly asked question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The L200 compares the voltage on pin 4 continuously with the 2.77 V reference voltage, and will increase or decrease the output voltage to keep pin 4 at that 2.77 V. So you can't simply supply a voltage there. If you would supply a voltage lower than 2.77 V the output would go to the maximum the L200 can supply in an attempt to raise the voltage on pin 4. And if the voltage is higher it will go as low as it can.

\$ V_{OUT} = \dfrac{R1 + R2}{R1} \cdot 2.77 V \$

You'll have to vary either of the resistors to control the output voltage. You could use a digital potmeter for this. With the given resistor values the output can go to +15 V. The [AD5290](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD5290.pdf) is a 10 kΩ potmeter which will work with voltages up to 30 V. It has 256 steps, so each step is about 50 mV.